# React/javascript load data by chunks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Can't undestand how to do it. My code now:

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isAllLoaded: false,
      dataItems: [],
    };
    this.serviceURL = URL;
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const {
      isAllLoaded,
      dataItems
    } = this.state;
    try {
      const {
        searchId
      } = await axios.get(`${this.serviceURL}/search`);
      // ????
      while (!isAllLoaded) {
        const {
          data
        } = await axios.get(`${this.serviceURL}/dataItems?searchId=${searchId}`);
        const chunkData = data.dataItems;
        const isStop = data.stop;

        this.setState({
          isAllLoaded: isStop,
          dataItems: [...dataItems, ...chunkData],
        });
      }
      // ????
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`failed: ${error}`); // failed: Error: Request failed with status code 500 :(
    }
  }
}
```

I need to get searchId,
Request: `URL/search`
Response: `{"searchId":"we5iD"}`

and then load all data items by chunks.
Request: `URL/dataItems?searchId=4niyd`
Response: `{dataItems: [], stop: false}`

In loaded chunks i got tocken "stop" that mark was is it last chunk or not.
I can get one chunk but how to keep loading until all chunks loadeed? when I tried this code i got error 500. Should I use 'while' with 'await' or something else?

Comment: 500 error is internal server error. Are you sure that you are sending a correct api request?

Comment: it return correct result when its not in while cycle. ```{dataItems: Array(300), stop: false}```

Comment: now I think its becouse sometimes server realy response with that error (500)... have no idea how to fix it, and resend request if I got this error.